# Float 2 divs in bootstrap 4 with flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 divs, that i want to float in the row or in the container div. 
With these classes, .justify-content-md-start and .justify-content-md-end, it does nothing. The divs are just simply next to each other without any float.

I also tryed classes like float-left, and float-right, but its was the same problem.

```
<div class="container kategoria_page_info_2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="justify-content-md-start"><span class="category_page_count_">Ebben a kategóriában összesen 7 termék található.</span></div>
            <div class="justify-content-md-end">
                <form method="get" name="listing_items">
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">
                        <option value="id_desc">Legújabb termékek</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="id_asc">Régebbiek elöl</option>
                        <option value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>
                        <option value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>
                        <option value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>
                        <option value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want, is to align the .justify-content-md-start div to the left side of the row, and align the justify-content-md-end div to the right side of the row.

[image]

Comment: With `justify-content-md-start` you specify that the content inside the div should be put to "start", not the div itself. For this you would need a class like `justify-self-start` (or with -md or whatever prefix you need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This class `.col-md-12` & `.justify-content-between`

```
<div class="container kategoria_page_info_2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 p-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class=""><span class="category_page_count_">Ebben a kategóriában összesen 7 termék található.</span></div>
            <div class="">
                <form method="get" name="listing_items">
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">
                        <option value="id_desc">Legújabb termékek</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="id_asc">Régebbiek elöl</option>
                        <option value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>
                        <option value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>
                        <option value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>
                        <option value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/7s5fuxpg/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/rqjdhm4L/ Updated version

Comment: That works fine, but these classes are giving some padding left and right to these 2 divs. How can i delete that?

Comment: `How can i delete that?` add class `p-0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.w-100` on the flex container and `.mr-auto` on the element you want to push to right. `.justify-content-md-start` and `.justify-content-md-end`. You can check [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment) doc for more example.

```
<div class="container kategoria_page_info_2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-100">
            <div class=""><span class="category_page_count_">Ebben a kategóriában összesen 7 termék található.</span></div>
            <div class="mr-auto">
                <form method="get" name="listing_items">
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">
                        <option value="id_desc">Legújabb termékek</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="id_asc">Régebbiek elöl</option>
                        <option value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>
                        <option value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>
                        <option value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>
                        <option value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```